# celery beat schedule with timezone configuration doesn't start at the the right time

Tags: python, timezone, celery

python version: 3.5.2
celery version: 4.1.0

server local timezone: Asia/Beijing Timezone +08:00 CST

celery settings:

```
timezone = "Asia/Shanghai"

beat_schedule = {
    "test.hello": {
        "task": "test.hello",
        "args": (),
        "schedule": crontab(minute=55, hour=22, day_of_week="Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri")
    },
```

}

but celery beat run the tasks start in `2017-08-02 07:01:00 CST`,

actually the task should start at `2017-08-01 22:55:00 +08:00`.

Comment: Are you using Django? And if so, did you reset the schedule manually as described [in the documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#time-zones)?

Answer (score 1):

Need to enable celery settings with `enable_utc` and `timezone`.

```
enable_utc = True
timezone = "Asia/Shanghai"
```

This can make the tasks run as we expected.

Otherwise celery schedule  will start as the `UTC` timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error where timezone was not updating even after changing it .

Use this to set your timezone other than UTC .

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai' # write your timezone
app.conf.enable_utc = False
```

This solution worked for me